# How to TryUpdateModel from outside of Controller in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

My app has modules that can be turned on and off and these modules are contributing to a view via Html.Partial calls. When the page posts back to the controller I want to have the modules take care of their individual models using something like TryUpdateModel that the controller has. Problem is that TryUpdateModel is a protected method and not accessible from outside the controller.

How can I do something like Controller.TryUpdateModel from a class outside of the controller?

Comment: Would you please post the code of your action method? And the way you access the partial views in you view? That would help big time.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading this right, it sounds like you are wanting a partial view to update itself.

I have done something similar with some jQuery, by calling an action and returning a partial view inside of a partial view. Inception?

Simple Example. - really simple

_partialViewStart.cshtml

```
<div id="partialFillerResult">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        loadPartialViewFiller();
    });
    function loadLatestTribes() {
        $("#partialFillerResult").load("@Url.Action("PartialViewFiller", "Home")").fadeIn("slow");
        setTimeout(loadPartialViewFiller, 5000);
    }
</script>
```

HomeController.cs

```
public ActionResult PartialViewFiller()
{
    var yourModel = new ExpandoObject();

    if (yourModel == null) return PartialView("_empty");
    return PartialView("_partialViewFiller", yourModel);
}
```

_partialViewFiller.cshtml

```
@model dynamic
<div class="objectWrapper">
    <p>
        @Model.Name
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't need the partial views to update themselves from the client. The entire page is posting to the controller. From there the controller needs to have the individual modules update their respective models. The closest thing I have been able to come up with is to extended the Controller class and expose the TryUpdateModel method as public, and then pass a reference to the controller to the individual modules

Comment: Can you use @Html.RenderAction()